# Rust throwing error 'attempt to use a non-constant value in a constant'

Tags: random, rust, constants

I'm a rust newbie and I wanted to understand why Rust is throwing me an error when I run the following code:

```rust
let rng = rand::thread_rng();
const NUMBER_TO_GUESS: u32 = rng.gen();
```

**Error:**

```
error[E0435]: attempt to use a non-constant value in a constant
  --> src/main.rs:12:34
   |
12 |     const NUMBER_TO_GUESS: u32 = rng.gen();
   |     ---------------------        ^^^ non-constant value
   |     |
   |     help: consider using `let` instead of `const`: `let NUMBER_TO_GUESS`
```

Comment: A `const` needs to be known at compile time. For this to work, the `gen` function would need to be a const function, which is not possible, as explained here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/const_eval.html#const-functions

Comment: It looks like you might be coming from a Javascript background of `let` (mutable) vs `const` (immutable) but the declarations in Rust are different: `let mut` (mutable) vs `let` (immutable).

Comment: This is way more complex than I thought, I guess assumed that the basic `let` and `const` knowledge would transfer from javascript world. 

yes @kmdreko, you're right. Still a lot to learn...

Answer (score 4):

If you really want a `const` (generated during compile time and does not change each time the program is run), then `cargo add const-random` and use the following:

```rust
use const_random::const_random;

fn main() {
    const NUMBER_TO_GUESS: u32 = const_random!(u32);
    println!("Hello {}", NUMBER_TO_GUESS);
}
```

I see that the variable is named `NUMBER_TO_GUESS`. A guessing game should probably change the number on each run, so you would use the following:

```rust
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    // rng needs to be mut because it needs to be modified so that
    // rng.gen() returns different values each time
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let number_to_guess: u32 = rng.gen();
    println!("Hello {}", number_to_guess);
}
```

I see in the comments you are from Javascript. Here is a table with some roughly corresponding syntax:

| Typescript | Rust |
| --- | --- |
| `let x: Something = y;` | `let mut x = y;` |
| `let x: Readonly<Something> = y;` | `let mut x = &y;` |
| `const x: Something = y;` | `let x = &mut y;` |
| `const x: Readonly<Something> = y;` | `let x = y;` |
| Closest is Webpack's EnvironmentPlugin/DefinePlugin with `const x: string = process.env.SOMETHING;` plus a minifier | `const x = "That thing";` |

In the Rust code you have, you see `let rng` before `const NUMBER_TO_GUESS`. The compiler does not see it this way. Ahead-of-time compiled languages always calculate the `const` one before other variables.